# Can a website incur liability for linking to a funding campaign for a lawsuit against it?

Tags: internet, liability, new-york-state, publishing

A large website that hosts user-created content has recently [announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338354/628364) that it is redacting links to a fundraising campaign for a lawsuit against it "under direction from [its] legal team." Is there a theory of liability under which there is some legal risk for hosting said links?

Assume any action would be under Second Circuit and New York state law.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes

The directors of a company have a fiduciary duty to act within the law for the benefit of their shareholders - not to their customers, not to the government, not to the environment and not to the public.

A lawsuit against the company will incur financial loss irrespective of if it is won or lost. It is difficult to see how it is in the shareholder's interest for the company to be enabling the funding of a lawsuit against it.

Comment: If the removal of said links harms the relation with the community, and the companies value is largely based on [goodwill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodwill_(accounting)), one could argue that it is in the shareholders benefit to leave the links as they are.

Comment: So what is the legal risk? And to whom? Is it the CEO? Would the CEO be opening themselves to a personal lawsuit from the shareholders? Would the company as a legal entity be opening itself to a lawsuit from the shareholders? Why are the links to the fundraiser page specifically a problem? Are user names mentioning the law suit different? Could you please expand this answer?

Comment: @DeltaLima It is true there is a counter argument, but the OP just asked for "a theory of liability under which there is some risk".  This answer gives one such theory.

Comment: The irony is that the Streisand effect means that removing such links aggravates the problem. It's literally a lose/lose when it comes to this. Therefore, the company already broke it's fiduciary duty by letting the situation escalate to that point.

Comment: @MSalters That assumes that the company actually did something wrong that resulted in the lawsuit. In any case, it's too late to undo that. Their fiduciary duty now is to try to minimize the damage. Companies are sued all the time, does that mean they're all violating fiduciary duty?

Comment: This misstates the fiduciary duty of directors, at least in the states I'm familiar with. The legal obligation is to act in the best interest of the company, rather than the individual director. This is different from acting in the shareholders interest, at the expense of, e.g., employees, the environment, etc. In practice, you only risk liability as a fiduciary if your actions  benefit yourself over the company.

Comment: @MSalters the did not break their fiduciary duty. Screwing up a business decision is not a breach of duty - they can make mistakes.